# Meteor add-platform error with $ANDROID_HOME

Tags: android, linux, cordova, meteor, environment-variables

I am trying to add android to my meteor project on ubuntu and am getting an error related to the $ANDROID_HOME variable.

```
$ meteor --verbose add-platform android 
Adding platform Android to Cordova project    
% Adding android project...                   
android: added platform                       
Checking Cordova requirements for platform Android

Your system does not yet seem to fulfill all requirements to build apps for Android.

Please follow the installation instructions here:
https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Mobile-Development-Install:-Android-on-Linux

Status of the requirements:                   
✓ Java JDK                                    
✓ Android SDK                                 
✗ Android target: Android SDK not found. Make sure that it is installed. If it is not at the default location, set the ANDROID_HOME environment
  variable.
✓ Gradle
```

I don't quite understand this error since it seems to be recognizing that there is an SDK but then can't find it.

This is what I have added to the bottom of my ~/.bashrc file:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/home/sarah/Android/Sdk/tools/
export PATH=${PATH}:/home/sarah/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/
export ANDROID_HOME=/home/sarah/Android/Sdk/
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools/
```

I've been trying to fix this for a few days, so since adding that, I have not only run `source ~/.bashrc` but have also logged out and back in and have restarted my computer.

Here's what my `$ANDROID_HOME` looks like if that's any help:

```
$ ls -l $ANDROID_HOME
total 40
drwxrwxr-x  2 sarah sarah 4096 Mar  1 20:45 add-ons
drwxrwxr-x  4 sarah sarah 4096 Feb 23 11:24 build-tools
drwxrwxr-x  4 sarah sarah 4096 Feb 22  2015 extras
drwxrwxr-x  3 sarah sarah 4096 Mar  1 20:45 platforms
drwxrwxr-x  5 sarah sarah 4096 Feb 11 11:54 platform-tools
-rw-rw-r--  1 sarah sarah 1158 Mar 21  2014 SDK Readme.txt
drwxrwxr-x  3 sarah sarah 4096 Mar  1 20:45 sources
drwxrwxr-x  3 sarah sarah 4096 Feb 22  2015 system-images
drwxrwxr-x  2 sarah sarah 4096 Mar  1 20:43 temp
drwxrwxr-x 12 sarah sarah 4096 Feb 11 12:50 tools
```

I have looked at many other threads about similar problems and haven't found a solution. For example, many folks mistakenly use `sudo` but I don't think that's my problem.

However, per the request of a commenter who has since deleted their comments I have tried running it with `sudo`. That did not solve the issue.

EDIT: I tried reinstalling Android Studio and the SDK version 22 and am still getting the same errors. These are [the instructions](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Mobile-Development-Install:-Android-on-Linux) I am following-- are they out of day?

EDIT: In a last-ditch effort to try and fix this, I tried to install Android and Cordova using [these instructions](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/09/install-android-cordova-ionic-framework-ubuntu/). Now I get a fancy new error having to do, presumably, with my Cordova install:

```
$ meteor add-platform --verbose android
   Adding platform Android to Cordova project    
=> Errors executing Cordova commands:         

   While adding platform Android to Cordova project:
   Cordova error: CordovaError: Failed to fetch platform android
   Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect.
   Check your connection and platform name/version/URL.
   undefined
   at
   /home/sarah/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.ki0ccv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/platform.js:270:25
   at _rejected
   (/home/sarah/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.ki0ccv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/q/q.js:797:24)
   at
   /home/sarah/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.ki0ccv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/q/q.js:823:30
   at Promise.when
   (/home/sarah/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.ki0ccv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/q/q.js:1035:31)
   at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch
   (/home/sarah/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.ki0ccv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/q/q.js:741:41)
   at
   /home/sarah/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.ki0ccv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/q/q.js:557:44
   at flush
   (/home/sarah/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.ki0ccv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
   at process._tickCallback (node.js:448:13)
   (If the error message contains suggestions for a fix, note that this may not apply to the
   Meteor integration. You can try running again with the --verbose option    to help diagnose the
   issue.)
```

No idea how to fix this; any clues appreciated.

Comment: Yep- I get errors again, but this time for Android SDK, Android target, and Gradle instead of just Android target.

Comment: I tried it. After running those commands, `sudo meteor --verbose add-platform android` still produced the same errors and `meteor --verbose add-platform android` did not have access to run at all. I changed the ownership back to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by first deleting the Cordova cache:

```
$ sudo rm -r ~/.cordova/lib/npm_cache
```

And then I reinstalled the Android sdk and tools by running `/opt/android-sdk/tools/android` to open the SDK manager.